# nginx client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking

Tags: ssl

about to bash my head against the wall after trying to sort this for over a week so really hoping someone can shed some light on where I've gone wrong with nginx!

I have this nginx.conf file which works perfectly (the way I want anyway)

```
events {
     worker_connections  4096; 
    }
        stream {
    upstream stream_backend {
        server backendapp:80;
    }
    server {
        listen                443 ssl;
        listen                8080;
        proxy_pass            stream_backend;
        ssl_certificate       ssl.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key   ssl.key;
        ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout   4h;
        ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
        #ssl_client_certificate ca.crt;
        #ssl_verify_client on;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
     }
}
```

However, I've been asked to enable client certificate, and when I remove the comments from `#ssl_client_certificate ca.crt;` and `#ssl_verify_client on;` I get these error logged in nginx `*13 client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.65.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443`

This is despite me sending client certs as part of the request.

I've scoured the internet and have found various solutions but none have worked for me so far (including here at SO). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using curl like so
`curl -v -k C:\Temp\opscert\user.key -cert C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt https://local.example.com`
and 
`curl -vk --key C:\Temp\opscert\user.key -cert C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt https://local.example.com`

also with powershell for good measure
`Invoke-WebRequest https://local.example.com -CertificateThumbprint 3b23775c0abfa0e9cb43e87b206dd6992ffc7e07`

Additionally, I would have expected browsers to prompt for a certificate when browsing to https://local.example.com/ but none do, I've tried on firefox, IE and Chrome.

The only time chrome did request a certificate once is when I changed `ssl_verify_client on;` to `ssl_verify_client optional;` however this is not what we want.

Here are the errors from nginx

```
2018/11/23 17:21:42 [info] 6#6: *21 client 192.168.65.3:58176 connected to 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:21:42 [info] 6#6: *21 client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.65.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:21:43 [info] 6#6: *22 client 192.168.65.3:58178 connected to 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:21:43 [info] 6#6: *22 client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.65.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:21:48 [info] 6#6: *23 client 192.168.65.3:58194 connected to 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:21:48 [info] 6#6: *23 client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.65.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:22:18 [info] 6#6: *24 client 192.168.65.3:58256 connected to 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:22:18 [info] 6#6: *24 client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.65.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:23:18 [info] 6#6: *25 client 192.168.65.3:58378 connected to 0.0.0.0:443
2018/11/23 17:23:18 [info] 6#6: *25 client sent no required SSL certificate while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.65.3, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Response from curl

```
PS C:\Users\abx> curl -v -k C:\Temp\opscert\user.key -cert C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt https://client.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: C:\Temp\opscert\user.key/
* Port number ended with '\'
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'
* Rebuilt URL to: C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt/
* Port number ended with '\'
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'
* Rebuilt URL to: https://client.example.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to client.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=GB; ST=Surrey; L=London; O=H. Example Company Ltd; CN=*.example.com
*  start date: Jan  5 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 10 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: client.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host client.example.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
PS C:\Users\abx> curl -vk --key C:\Temp\opscert\user.key -cert C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt https://local.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt/
* Port number ended with '\'
* Closing connection -1
curl: (3) Port number ended with '\'
* Rebuilt URL to: https://local.example.com/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to client.example.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=GB; ST=Surrey; L=London; O=H. Example Company Ltd; CN=*.example.com
*  start date: Jan  5 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Jan 10 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: client.example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.59.0
> Accept: */*
>
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host client.example.com left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Comment: *"..This is despite me sending client certs as part of the request..."* - likely you don't. Please show how your client sends the client cert as you claim. The configuration of the server side only shows that the server requests a client certificate but not that the client actually sends one.

Comment: `-k` (as shown in the question and at first in the comment) is not the option for curl to specify the private key but to ignore certificate errors but `--key` is (as shown second). Given that the problem is the client likely not sending the command it does not help a lot to show the server side errors only and especially not the same error 6 times. Please include the verbose output (`-v`) of the correct curl command into your question-

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is not just with curl, I've tried with powershell and with 3 different browsers with all showing the same error in server which is the reason behind same error showing 6 times. Will get a verbose log output for curl but as I said this isn't restricted to just curl.

Comment: Maybe its not restricted to curl but curl usually provides verbose output usable to debug such a problem while the others don't.

Comment: I've updated the question to include output from curl, do let me know if there's anything else missing.

Comment: The options should be `--key` and `--cert`, not `-k` (first try) and `-cert` (both tries). This way you effectively don't properly specify a certificate and that's why none will be send. But one can see that the server is requesting a certificate from the client and the client is sending a (likely empty since none was properly specified) certificate in the handshake, so the server part seems to work.

Comment: You can even see in the log it is treating the filenames for `-k` and `-cert` as URLs (that can't be fetched) NOT as key & cert files. And (@SteffenUllrich) the fact it doesn't send CertificateVerify for ECDHE-RSA confirms it sent an empty Certificate message (which is normal for TLS, although it wasn't for SSL).

Comment: What should be the expected behaviour when accessing the site using a Web browser? I was presuming a prompt from browser to select a certificate but we don't see that.

Comment: @BoredAtWork: I suggest that you focus on one problem at a time, i.e. first get it working with curl by using the proper and well documented options instead of second-guessing how the options should look like but guessing wrong. The browser will only prompt you if it has a client certificate installed matching the list of CA send by the server - which needs a) the client certificate properly installed in the browser and b) the server sending the right list of accepted CA. This adds another layer of complexity and easy to get wrong things compared to curl so please get curl running first.

Comment: Agreed, it was a more question at this point due to looking at this problem for so long. It's 6am right now and I'm still reading about client certs! I'll get it working with curl first as suggested.

Comment: thank you very much @SteffenUllrich, I've finally managed to get it to work. You were correct, the problem was I was sending the pfx cert imported into the windows cert store, once I imported just the user.crt and send this it worked.

Answer (score 0):

for powershell import just the user.crt (not pfx)

for curl, same thing, use user.crt `curl -v --key C:\Temp\opscert\user.key --cert C:\Temp\opscert\user.crt https://client.example.com`

I'd still prefer if when accessing via a browser I was prompted to for cert working but for now this is perfect as the requests will come from an api.